# Where does Pandas store metadata info?

Tags: pandas, metadata

Where does pandas store its metadata information?
For eg. if pandas.dataframe.info() is executed, it returns the metadata information.

Where is this metadata getting stored? or do Pandas generate it dynamically without storing anywhere?
Also, if it is getting stored, how to find the memory usage the metadata is taking?

Answer (score 1):

It is not stored, it is computed on demand.

This is done by `DataFrameInfo`, you can check the source of [pandas.io.formats.info](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.2/pandas/io/formats/info.py)